Find the limit and give the strict $\epsilon - \delta$ proof that: $\lim_{x\to 1^{+}}$ $x\lfloor x \rfloor$
This is from Advance Calculus Theory and Practice By John S. Petrovic. The book has the answer in the back but I need some clarity on $\delta$.
Answer: The limit is 1. Let $\epsilon > 0$, and choose $\delta = \min{(1,\epsilon)}$. If $1 < x < 1 +\delta$ then $\lfloor x \rfloor = 1$, so $|x \lfloor x \rfloor - 1| = | x-1| < \epsilon$.
Where/how are they choosing the minimum? Does it have to do with $\lfloor x \rfloor = 1$ and $| x-1| < \epsilon$? Are they assuming a number and using the opposite to find the other?

the minimum can be imposed because only small values of $\delta$ are important. For big values you can choose a random number and find an upper quote for $\epsilon$

They impose the min because then $\lfloor x \rfloor = 1$, so you get a simple formula for $x\lfloor x \rfloor-1 .$ Introducions to analysis are full of these simplifying "tricks".

@hellofriends I wouldn't say it's because big $\delta$ is unimportant, it's because the prover has complete control over the value of $\delta$, and how small $\delta$ should be. The "big values are unimportant" reasoning applies to assumptions about how small $\varepsilon$ can be.

@TheoBendit yes, that's what I wanted to say. I also meant lower quote for $\epsilon$ instead of upper (all the $\epsilon$ above this quote would satisfy the property)

@hellofriends And I likewise meant to say "assumptions about how big $\varepsilon$ can be." :)

I speculate that the choice of $~\delta \leq 1~$ is designed to guarantee that $~\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor = 1.~$  As indicated by the comment of Steen, this guarantee simplifies the analysis.
So, with the constraint on $~\delta~$ that it is $~\leq 1,~$ the constraint that $~1 < x < 1 + \delta~$ does imply that $~1 < x < 2,~$ as intended.

Thank you, I'm not sure I quite get it yet but this is helpful. I'm going to go try a few more!

Recall that once we have $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ we need it to be true that
$$\forall x : (0 < x - 1 < \delta \implies 
\lvert x \lfloor x \rfloor - 1\rvert  < \epsilon). \tag1 $$
(Since this is a one-sided limit, we don't take the absolute value of
$x - 1$.)
Suppose we had the strategy to prove the existence of a suitable $\delta$ for every $\epsilon$ by simply setting $\delta = \epsilon$ without the $\min$ function.
Since the definition of a limit says "for all $\epsilon > 0$,"
a proof should cover all possible positive values of $\epsilon$.
One such value of $\epsilon$ is $2$.
Using the simple strategy $\delta = \epsilon$, when presented with $\epsilon = 2$
we would have $\delta = 2$.
But then there exists a value of $x$, in particular $x = 2.5$, such that
$0 < x - 1 = 1.5 < \delta$
but $\lvert x \lfloor x \rfloor - 1\rvert = 4 \not< \epsilon$.
Therefore the implication in $(1)$ is not true for all $x$ and our proof strategy has failed.
Basically, if there is any way that $\lfloor x \rfloor$ can be greater than $1$, we're going to be in trouble on the right-hand side of the implication.
The strategy $\delta = \min\{1,\epsilon\}$ is a way to avoid this kind of failure.
There are other ways the problem might be solved, but this is a very popular technique.
